# NSFetchedResultsController trying to limit number of records displayed

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

When creating a `NSFetchRequest` to pass over to my `NSFetchedResultsController` I am setting the fetchLimit property to 3.

Now initially this appears to work fine. I can modify the first three returned objects in any way which changes their order and they all reshuffle correctly. The problem appears when I either alter a object which initially fell outside the first three in a way which now brings it into the first three, or when simply adding a new object so it will appear within the first three.

What I expected to happen: Inserted object pushes the rest down and one drops off the bottom.

What actually happens: Inserted object pushes the rest down and the **record count grows to 4**?!

Can anyone explain this, or how I should deal with this?

Comment: Do you re-execute the fetch or do you simply listen to the changes?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, maybe consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Just listening for changes using the delegate methods

Comment: Did your try refetching in cases of inserts and deletes?

Comment: Would need to be with moves too. But this defeats the purpose of NSFetchedResultsController I may as well just keep an array.

Comment: I absolutely agree, this would simply be a way around the bug. But from your description I would say: "file a radar"

Comment: How do you add that object?Using some "Add" button?Or with the sane fetchedresultscontroller?

Comment: Say the objects are sorted by their date property, and it is set to pull out the first three. I set object.date = now then that object will move to the top and the others move down. However if the object wasn't already in the first three it will insert correctly and move the others down, but the last one doesn't drop off, there are now 4 objects. It doesn't really matter how the objected is added or moved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made some progress working around this, basically by ignoring `numberOfObjects` and returning the actual length I want the table fixed at. This takes a bit of trickery in `controller:didChangeObject:...` but seems to be working so far.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return kTableSize;
    //return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.myTableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

            // Only modify table if insert will effect visible rows
            if (newIndexPath.row < kTableSize) {
                // Delete last row to maintain fixed length
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(kTableSize - 1) inSection:newIndexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

            // Only modify table if delete will effect visible rows
            if (indexPath.row < kTableSize) {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

                // Insert extra row to maintain fixed length
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(kTableSize - 1) inSection:newIndexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:

            // Only modify table if update will effect visible rows
            if (indexPath.row < kTableSize) {
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:

            // Only modify table if move will effect visible rows
            if ((indexPath.row < kTableSize) || (newIndexPath.row < kTableSize)) {


                // Delete old row or last row of table
                if (indexPath.row < kTableSize) {
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                } else {
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(kTableSize - 1) inSection:newIndexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                }

                // Insert new row or a row at bottom of table
                if (newIndexPath.row < kTableSize) {
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                } else {
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(kTableSize - 1) inSection:newIndexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Also need to take care in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to make sure we don't try and access an object which doesn't exist if there are less objects than the table length.